# Unable to connect to database C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, connection-string

I've been trying to connect to my MS Sql database through the connection string in my App.config, but for some reason it fails to login, i just can't seem to figure it out.

This is my Connection method:

```
public void Con()
{

        string userName = userNameBox.Text;
        string passWord = passWordBox.Text;

        bool loginFail;

        SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["lagerConn"].ConnectionString);

        //Search Connstring for User ID= & Password= and replace with username and password from Textboxes
        if (_Connstring.Contains("User ID="))
        {
            _Connstring = _Connstring.Replace("User ID=;", "User ID=" + userName + ";");

        }
        if (_Connstring.Contains("Password="))
        {
            _Connstring = _Connstring.Replace("Password=", "Password='" + passWord + "'");
        }

        try
        {
            Conn.Open();
            Conn.Close();
            loginFail = false;
        }catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login Failed");
            loginFail = true;
        }
        if(loginFail == false) //If login is successful it will change to the next form and hide the Connect form
        {
            mainMenu secondForm = new mainMenu();
            secondForm.Show();
            this.Hide();

        }

    }`
```

And here is my App.config

```
        <add name="lagerConn" connectionString="Data Source=LagerServer;Initial Catalog=LagerDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=;Password="
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

[I got this exception](http://gyazo.com/d312025a0af3592ebbd64bf72435f442)

Comment: You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. And **don't store your passwords as a plain text**. Use hashing functions as SHA-512.

Comment: can you give us the exception you received while connecting

Comment: Here is the exception http://gyazo.com/d312025a0af3592ebbd64bf72435f442

Comment: you should include the exception as an edit in your question, for convenience

Comment: Please check `http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no point putting an empty user ID and password field in the connection string at all.  Just leave them out altogether and get rid of that pointless `Persist Security Info` too.  Use a connection string builder, e.g.

```
SqlConnection builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["lagerConn"].ConnectionString);

builder.UserID = userID;
builder.Password = password;

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
```

After that, don't just provide a generic error message and ignore the information the system gives you.  Look at the exception and it will tell you what went wrong.

Comment: This helped me out big time, thanks a lot, i still have a long way obviously hehe.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
string userName = userNameBox.Text;
string passWord = passWordBox.Text;
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["lagerConn"].ConnectionString;
connStr = connStr.Replace("User ID=;", "User ID=" + userName + ";");
connStr = connStr.Replace("Password=", "Password='" + passWord + "'");
bool loginFail = false;
try{
    using (SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(connStr){
       loginFail true;
    }
}
catch (SqlConnection sqlEx){
   //already false
}
```

And yes, beware of sql injection attacks!

Answer (score 0):

First you should not write UserID and Password in TextBoxes write them static in connection string. The exception told you everything-> Login failed for user ''. You didn't write correct user or password in the textbox.